# OAuth 2.0 authentication for own mobile client

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, oauth2orize

I am developing an app using node.js which will also have an mobile client. I am looking to make the authentication using OAuth 2.0. Is there any good module which allows me to have OAuth 2.0 authentication server?

I looked at a subsidiary module of Passport "OAuth2orize". I found it quite good enough, but the real problem was understanding how it will work for my own app (the example and docs specify about third party authorisation).

Basically what I want is that the client logs in with client id, user's username, user's password and there by I hand him a token after verifying the above 3 things. But the problem with Oauth2orize is that there there are redirect URI and all which is confusing me a lot.

Please help me know as to how can i achieve this using Oauth2rize or any other really good module. Or If its easy enough I can also roll my own, but will that be a good idea regarding security ??

Comment: Same problem here, I do not quite get the internal stuff of oauth2orize and do not manage to integrate it in my app (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005627/securing-a-nodejs-sailsjs-api-with-oauth2). Any update so far ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-38) flow. As you've seen, the examples for oauth2 do not include functionality that supports this flow. In fact the examples only cover the [Authorization Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-24) flow.

It should end up being fairly easy to implement. All you need to do is accept a request that contains the information you are looking for (and authorize it) and create a token in your token database and return it. As long as you use the same token database that the rest of oauth2orize is using, it should work just fine. See: [Passing Trusted Client Information with oAuth2orize for the "Resource Owner Password Flow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654078/passing-trusted-client-information-with-oauth2orize-for-the-resource-owner-pass/16672677#16672677) where that is exactly what is suggested.

**Correction:**
The all-grants example of oauth2orize supports the Implicit flow as well as Authorization Code flow.